# Adding DevTools dependency gives error running spring boot application in STS

Tags: maven, spring-boot, devtools

After adding DevTools I am having the following error which is preventing my application to run in STS. The error and my `pom.xml` is as follows.

**Error:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to
>   read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar
>   file:/C:/Users/Jahadul%20Rakib/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:132)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.fromClassLoader(ChangeableUrls.java:98)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:92)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.(Restarter.java:142)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:556)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:76)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:50)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>   at com.book.BookShopApplication.main(BookShopApplication.java:33)
>   Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad
>   signature) at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source) at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromManifestClassPathAttribute(ChangeableUrls.java:153)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:129)
>   ... 17 more

**pom.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rakib.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>book-shop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>book-shop</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr-complete</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Something was wrong with your dependency, please try to remove those dependency from your .m2/repository.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your .m2 repository has corrupted dependancy `antlr-2.7.7.jar` try to `remove antlr-2.7.7.jar` and clean and rebuild your project. If this doesn't help then remove the `whole .m2 repository` will surely help you.

---

you can find .m2 repository Here

```
C:/Users/Jahadul%20Rakib/.m2
```